# Trying to Change Active Window in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I am running a set of protractor specs in Jenkins and when the steps open a new window, Jenkins never seems to handle the switch of focus to the new window.

My spec contains code like:

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
newWindowHandle = handles[1];
browser.switchTo.window(newWindowHandle).then(function() {
     steps in new window -- which fail
     browser.driver.close().then(function() {
      browser.switchTo.window(handle[0]);
     });
});
```

These scripts work fine when I run protractor at the Linux command line.  I am able to change to the new window, execute steps in that new window, then return to the old window.   But when the specs run in Jenkins, they error at that point and the screenshot that is taken automatically at the error displays window[0] not window[1].    Is there something different that needs to be done to get Jenkins to switch window focus?

Comment: Because it's not opened for that time. Protractor will know about that windows ONLY after it will be loaded fully.

Comment: The window is loaded (the step to launch the window is before this code).   Protractor has no problem with this when I run it without Jenkins.  It's only in Jenkins that the switch doesn't occur.